# What can we say of eigenvaluesof $L=D-A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a nonnegative, symmetric, $n\times n$ matrix A, the Laplacian L 
of A is defined to be
$$L=D-A$$
where $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,...,d_n)$ and $d_k=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj}$; I observe thta $L$ is symmetric and it does not depend on the diagonal entries of $A$. What can we say of its eigenvalues? They should all be positive ... why?

Comment: Take $A$ to be the identity, then $L$ is 0!

Comment: In fact, $0$ will always be an eigenvalue of $L$, because the column sum of each column is $L$, hence adding the rows together produces $0$, hence $L$ is singular. And because $L$ is symmetric, this implies $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "nonnegative" in the context of matrices? Are you referring to the entries of $A$ being nonnegative, or that $A$ is positive semi-definite, or something else?

Comment: @TheoBendit, yes I refer to the entries of $A$.

Comment: You might be referring to specific matrices $A$, such as graph incidence matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $L$ is positive *semidefinite*. Just compute the Gershgorin circles.

Comment: (To asker): see the [wiki page on the Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)